# HTML not formatted properly

Tags: jquery, html, html-parsing

I'm trying to get the HTML from another domain (Google for the example). I use [this library](https://github.com/padolsey-archive/jquery.fn/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax), and I can get the HTML with it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://google.fr',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(res) {            
            $html = $(res.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

The string returned by `res.responseText` contains all the HTML, but when I do `$(res.responseText)`, there isn't all the tags, for example I can't get the title by doing `$(res.responseText).find("title")`. I even tried the function `$.parseHTML`, I have the same result. Why is my HTML not parsed correctly?

Comment: can you specify the `dataType`

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: after `type` add `dataType:json` it is just and example it can be text , html depending on what you need

Comment: @guradio That's HTML. Not JSON. Don't confuse the OP. And jQuery is smart enough to parse it and understand when it is HTML / JSON.

Comment: What does `res.responseText` contain?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/HgKt57p1

Comment: Wow. Are you sure? Can you get a screenshot of `console.log(res.responseText)` and also what does, `$("<div />", {html: res.responseText})` gives you?

Comment: @PraveenKumar i am not confusing the OP as i stated above it is example it can be text html depending on what OP needs

Comment: @guradio I do understand. Not needed in this aspect.

Comment: @PraveenKumar i guess it could help if he can send a whole HTML response then he can just do `$('body').html(response)` what would be cleaner right?

Comment: The screenshot : http://i.imgur.com/n5WZ8kL.png (not complete)

And for $("<div />", {html: res.responseText}) I have :http://i.imgur.com/lFts5yB.png

Comment: @Eko Looks like the `div` thing actually worked. Try assigning it to something: `$html = $("<div />", {html: res.responseText});` And later, try `$html.find("title")`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar yes, it works now. Thanks !

Comment: @Eko Will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything works as expected, but let's create a fake element:

```
$html = $("<div />", {html: res.responseText});
$html.find("title"); // This would work.
```

Comment: i have one question you didnt suggest to define the dataType as html does this line `{html: res.responseText}` do it?im just curious never done it like this

Comment: @guradio Well, it was my gut feeling, when the response is received well, we'll create a div element and add it. And it worked. `:)` Even I have never done like this. First time. `:P`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like this ?

https://jsfiddle.net/omsmvksg/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://google.fr',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType : 'html',
        success: function(res) {
            console.log(res.responseText);
            $html = $(res.responseText);
            console.log($html.find("._yKg").length);
        }
    });
});
```

It logs the good count of `_yKg` class in the html downloaded.

[image]